# What is the use of SET type in MySQL? How to implement in Oracle?

Tags: mysql, oracle

I was reading on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set.html but I could not understand its use much. Why do we need it?
And how can we achieve this in Oracle?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, why are you reading MySQL docs if you're actually using Oracle?

Comment: I am trying to convert an Oracle database to MySQL. My mentor suggests I should understand the differences  in the features provided first.

Comment: I see. Always add as much explanation as you can to your questions, it will help us understand your goal better and make it easier to answer your questions more accurately. Welcome to SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do we need it? We don't. Anything that you think you can do with a set, you can do with a parent-child relationship. You can even cluster tables if you so desire, which I suppose could be a concern.

The closest concept in Oracle to a MySQL SET is what Oracle calls a nested table.

The biggest problem with nested tables is that you would be hard-pressed to index them.